Google App Script, Find value and write a result
I have a form where the answers arrive on a google excel sheet. I would like the script to do this:
Each new row that is created:
In column "I" if I have this value "Light or gray hair" it must write in column J "No"
In column "I" if I have other values ​ ​ that are not "Light or gray hair" it must write in column J "OK"

How to use Form Submit using App script
Try to use this approach with conditional statements and on form submit using Apps Script.
You will need to adjust your range depending on your data set.
Script used
function myfunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var values = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  console.log(values);
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) { 
    var color = values[i][8];
    if (color === ""){
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 10, 1, 1).setValue('');
    }
    else if (color.toLowerCase() === 'light gray' || color.toLowerCase() === 'gray hair') {
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 10, 1, 1).setValue('NO');
      console.log(color);
    } else {
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 10, 1, 1).setValue('OK'); 
    }
  }
}

Sample Output
Spreadsheet

Add triggers

==========================================================================
Other Option using Google Sheet Formula
if you are open to an alternative solution other than using Google apps script to satisfy your expected result. I would suggest using Google sheet formula for easier implementation. Just paste this formula in Column J2 and make that of no value in ColumnJ.
=BYROW(I2:I, LAMBDA(row, IF(row <> "", IF(OR(LOWER(row) = "light gray", row = "gray hair"), "NO", "OK"), "")))

Google Sheet Formula Sample Output

Reference

Triggers
Conditional Statement


First of all thanks. Fantastic
I'm trying to configure the script but it still doesn't work for me.
The input FORM is not from GOOGLE but from OPINIONSTAGE that connects to the google excel sheet with Zapier.
Is it a problem for the functioning?

Another question
Is it possible to set a control of the value of cell "i"
If it says "LIGHT GRAY" it must write on cell "j" NO
In all other cases, if it does not find "LIGHT GRAY" but any other writing and text, it must write on cell "j" OK
Thanks

I have added this answer just to get you started on the right path, if you have any chance to review understand the code I have provided it is going to  be great for you. Moreover, if you really can't start learning and understanding Apps Script, this is also achievable using a Google Sheet Formula. Where you can easily dive in and learn. The Google Formula is provided above.

Patsytalk Thank you so much for this script. Tested and working. Really awesome.
A question. What if I wanted to check the data on two cells instead of one? Is it possible?
